# Sub menu creation

Tags: routes, navigation

I need to create page level menus.  User goes to a page off of the main menu and is presented with a sub menu.  The menu items need to display / not display based on user roles - similar to the main menu.   I researched the Book and the Blocks... but I don't know if either of these are the way to do it.    It seems like a very common thing - and want to know the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu Block module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) provides blocks that you can place via the Block API. [Menu position](https://drupal.org/project/menu_position) might also be useful - it "allows for the creation of rules that will dynamically add the current page into the menu system at the requested spots."

Comment: I need the menu to be stand alone, not duplicated from the main menu.  Basically, the main menu will bring the user to a content page and that page needs a list of links to other related content.     The thing is I need the links to appear or not appear based on roles/permissions.

Comment: If your "sub menu" is not derived from the main menu, then it's not a "sub menu" at all, it is just another menu. You can set roles on the block settings for it either way.